Pause/Play toggle for Lottie playback does not successfully 'pause'
I am attempting to create a pause/play button 'toggle' for Lottie animation playback. The button appearance is provided by Font Awesome icons, defined in javascript to shaw a 'play' state when the animation is inactive, and a 'pause' state when the animation is active. The 'play' behavior appears to work as expected, however, 'pause' does not.
The issue does not elicit browser console errors, leading me to think that the EventListener is inadequately defined.
I have tried different methods to define the 'pause' javascript, but my code does not successfully stop the Lottie animation from playing.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Lottie Player Web Button Component</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0"
    />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.5.3/lottie_svg.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8a60cdf3a9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/yil7vfv.css">
    <style>
    body {
      font-family: Roboto;
      background: #fff;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 40vh;
    }
    .fa-regular {
      color: #666666;
      font-size:30px;
    }
    .my-icon {
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 24px;
    }    
    .my-text {
        font-family: "Courier-new";
    }    
    .my-fancy-container {
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 60px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #play-button {
      padding-right: 16px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="lottie-animation" background="transparent"  speed="0.5"  style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
<div>
  <a href="#" id="playPauseBtn"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i></a>
</div>
<script>
// Initialize Lottie player   
      const animation = lottie.loadAnimation({ 
        container: document.getElementById('lottie-animation'),      
        renderer: 'svg',       
        loop: true,       
        autoplay: false, // Set to false to initially not play      
        path: 'https://assets1.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/HN7OcWNnoqje6iXIiZdWzKxvLIbfeCGTmvXmEm1h/data.json' // Replace with your animation file      
      });
      
      // Get buttons
      const playPauseBtn = document.getElementById("playPauseBtn");  
      
      // Play button functionality
      playPauseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (animation.pause) {
          animation.play();
          playPauseBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-pause"></i>';
        } else {
          animation.pause();
          playPauseBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i>';
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


You just need to change if(animation.pause) to if(animation.isPaused)
.pause is a function pausing the animation.
// Initialize Lottie player
const animation = lottie.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById('lottie-animation'),
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: false, // Set to false to initially not play
  path: 'https://assets1.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/HN7OcWNnoqje6iXIiZdWzKxvLIbfeCGTmvXmEm1h/data.json' // Replace with your animation file
});

// Get buttons
const playPauseBtn = document.getElementById("playPauseBtn");

// Play button functionality
playPauseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // EDIT you need to check .isPaused, not .pause. .pause is a function pausing the animation
  // if (animation.pause) {
  if (animation.isPaused) {
    animation.play();
    playPauseBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-pause"></i>';
  } else {
    animation.pause();
    playPauseBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i>';
  }
});


Thank you, Ray, for your kind and helpful response. Your recommendation works perfectly. I was caught up in whether the logic was right or not, and didn't think about my malformed property for the animation state.
